# How to make login in silverlight navigation application template?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, forms-authentication

You really don't have Forms-authentication like in asp.net in Silverlight. What's the approach to make a login functionality in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF Ria services authentication in "forms" mode. Check out WCF Ria samples. Plenty of authentication related stuff there.

Comment: But I'm kind of weird or something, but I don't want to use WCF.